# Не получает нормально выровнять элементы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1)Если в этом прямоугольнике текст в 2 строки то начинается пляска прямоугольников

код html:

```
       @foreach($groups as $group)               
      <div class="panel5">
      {!! $group !!}</div> 
       @endforeach
```

код css:

```
 .panel5 {
border:#080808 solid 1px; 
width:154px;
height:100px;  
background:#408ccb;
display: inline-block;
text-align:center;
padding: 3em 0; 
color:#FFFFFF;
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word; 
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

2) серый прямоугольник не получается выравнять с остальными в одну линию потому что он в div блоке, а если его делаешь без дива он не так отображается(картинка растягивается на весь прямоугольник)

код html:

```
  <div class="panel3 outer" >
    <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0612/GooglePlusInterfaceIcons/w128h1281338911594add.png"    width="30" height="30"  onclick="history.back();">
  </div>
```

код css:

```
.panel3 {
border:#080808 solid 1px; 
width:154px;
height:100px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.outer {
height: 100px;
position: relative;
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, а то с версткой у меня прям беда, с бэкендом получше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Добавьте свойство вертикальное выравнивание блоков `vertical-align` со значением top или bottom или middle:

`vertical-align: top;` или `vertical-align: bottom;` или `vertical-align: middle;`

Любое из значений выровняет блоки в одну линию

2) Поставьте серому прямоугольнику свойство `display: inline-block;` это поставит его в одну линию, а если еще хотите выровнять по низу (или верху или середине) с остальными, то еще и одно из свойств из пункта 1.